# iPhone won't connect to home wireless network - but laptop will?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, iphone, home-networking

Just recently my iPhone stopped connecting to my home router.

It works elsewhere but is not connecting at home.  My laptop connects, but not my iPhone any longer.  When it asks me to choose a network - I select my home network and enter the password, and it then says:

> Unable to join the network “alexander” (Which is the name of my home
>   network.)

When I tap the blue circle, there is no IP address or anything else entered on that page. But I don’t know if there was ever anything there when it was working as I had no reason to look there when it was working.

I know what the password is, as I have it written down, but I have also tried two other passwords and it never says that it is an incorrect password, it just says:

> Unable to join the network.

Answer (score 1):

Try telling it to forget that network, and then try joining it again. Maybe the iPhone is holding onto a stale setting somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Go to: “Settings -> General -> Reset -> Reset network settings.”

That should fix it. It’s the best and only answer I got that was any use.